# Make a decal a physical object?

Tags: unreal-4, gameobject

Is there a way in the UE4 to make a decal such as a blood decal and give it a physical object? I want to do it so that I can add a sound affect when the player walks on the physical object, a box trigger wont work as when the player stands on it the sound will keep playing and repeating even if the player isn't moving.

Comment: You could add a boolean value that deactivates the trigger when the player is static. That way the sound will only play when you actually move.